# I filed for a Sole Proprietor EIN, but made no money. Do I need to file any tax forms?

Tags: united-states, taxes, sole-proprietorship, ein

Do I need to file any tax forms, with no money earned, for a sole proprietor with an EIN? I requested an EIN thinking that I was going to use it, but it has taken longer to get to a point of preparation than I had previously thought it would take. I don't have any income or expenses to report for last year, but I'm unsure if I need to file anything to declare that. What, if anything, do I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What, if anything, do I need to do? Thanks!

Nothing really.

Depending on what information you provided on SS-4, the IRS may come asking for payroll tax returns etc. In that case you'll have to respond describing the situation. If they don't - you won't.